# Rails 4 will pagination with Post Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pagination, will-paginate

Hi I am using gem "will_paginate" for pagination.

How to change the will_paginate get url into post

I am Using Rails 4 and Ruby 2

Comment: what do you mean by "get url into post"

Comment: Please Elaborate in more details.

Comment: yes In normal will_paginate sent url like                                                                  Get /3000/product/search?page=2                                                        I want to change the GET into POST because my controller method is POST

Comment: Do you mean something like this "localhost:3000/admin?Pictures=2"

Comment: Post some of your code please Paul because I think it's got something to do with your page parameters